# Web.config app settings properties inheritance in restapi

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have two applications set up as children of web app(service). Neither of them have "inheritInChildApplications" or "enableConfigurationOverride" properties in them. I do not see remove or clear tags anywhere as well. But one of them inherits settings from parent and the other one does not. Is there any other setting?

Found that there could be inheritInChildApplications property that could stop inheritance but I can't find it in my app(s)

I need certain properties from  to be inherited in child.

I am missing certain properties in child web app(Rest API) that should've come in from the parent.

They all have separate app pools.

Comment: @RyanK, any suggestions on this?

Comment: your root web.config states that the only default document is index.htm. However, your subfolder web.config states that the only default document is iisstart.htm. If there is no such file iisstart.htm in the subfolder, root setting which is index.htm will be inherited and used. In order to prevent root settings to be inherited, use inheritInChildApplications attribute in a location tag.`<location path="" inheritInChildApplications="false"> <system.webServer><defaultDocument enabled="true"><files><add value="index.htm" /></files></defaultDocument></system.webServer></location>`

Comment: refer this link for more detail: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/How-to-prevent-web-config-files-to-be-overwritten-by-config/ba-p/297627